# Cant use or access macros in Personal.xlsb

Tags: excel, vba

After a sudden unplanned power trip on I am no longer able to access my macros or view their code in Visual basic for excel.

If I try to access it now it only displays a grey box displaying the name of the macro but no code.

I've copied and sent it to a peer who can access and use all my macros. I've tried to delete my copy and replace it with the one I sent him, but the problem still persists.
I've tried to repair the file but it doesn't work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated as my last backups are from the beginning of November and don't include several new files

[image]

Comment: If you press Alt+F8 can you see any of your macros?  In the VBE try setting View >> Cascade in case your ode windows ended up off-screen.

Comment: nothing shows up when I use Alt+F8, I can see the actual code window its just blank and greyed out

Comment: Can you create a new macro in the workbook?

Comment: I cant make or edit any existing macros in the workbook. I can make macros in other workbooks but cant extract any of my already existing macros

Comment: Close all your Excel files and check in the Task Manager of the exist of any excel app.

Comment: I've done so, and left my work computer unplugged since Friday

Comment: After transmitting the file did you check its File...Properties for an "Unblock" checkbox/option? Sometimes when you send macro files back and forth like that, you have to unblock the file manually for security reasons.

Comment: I did and the problem still persists.

Comment: Try this: Save your old Personal.xlsb on another name. Create a new one and copy paste a macro to it from the old one as text from the machine where it can be achieved. This can test whether the file or the excel has a problem